# XML, where the find() method fails in a Boolean context

Tags: xml, methods, find

I'm reading Dive into Python 3 by Mark Pilgrim, and this passage perplexed me:

"There is a 'gotcha' with the find() method that will eventually bite you. In a Boolean context, ElementTree element objects will evaluate to False if they contain no children (that is, if len(element) is 0). This means that --if element.find('...')-- is not testing whether the find() method found a matching element; it's testing whether that matching element has any child elements! To test whether the find() method returned an element, use --if element.find('...') is not None--." page 195

What I don't understand is, the "is not None" part might evaluate to True, right? Then what is the purpose of the find() function in this context, if it shows ambiguous results?

edit: What I mean is, if the 'if' statement evaluates to false, then it tells me that either 1) It did not find children within the element matching the find() query, or 2) There are no children within the element! How is that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it turned out to be rather simple.

The find() method will return None if no children are found, and false if it has no child elements. So True --> children found, False --> no children in element, None --> children in element, but none matched the query.